# Python Django project handling .env and SECRET_KEY on GitHub Actions + Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, github-actions, infrastructure

We have a web service written in Django that is stored on GitHub. We used GitHub Actions to create a workflow that builds a Docker image and pushes it to Azure Container Registry. Then the workflow triggers a Terraform file that in turn provisions a Kubernetes Cluster and using a deployment.yaml it deploys the web service app on Kubernetes cluster.

This whole process works fine but when pods are up they get terminated `CrashLoopBackOff`

The terminated pod's log can be found in the ix output below
http://ix.io/2BCx

I know the log clearly shows that its missing some .env file and environment variables such as SECRET_KEY that seems to require these BEFORE the image build, we are unaware where and at what stage to provide these information to the image? Whether in the GH Actions workflow itself, in Dockerfile, a bash script to inject somewhere.

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure the tags python, django help at all here. Seems an infrastructure topic for the build process - your Terraform publish steps needs to provide the .env with needed parameters so docker-compose up command can spin up the container including the correct environment variables?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks, I changed the tags. Terraform is only spinning up a Kubernetes cluster and creating a resource group. I'm not sure if I could quite understand where to include .env file and required parameters. Terraform's step is just after the image is being pushed to Azure Container Registry. I can provide any other information if this isn't clarifying the process enough